# Push to local Azure DevOps Git from Build Pipeline

Tags: git, maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, maven-release-plugin

**Short version**

Can someone tell me how to set up a "Command Line Script" task within an Azure DevOps build pipeline that pushes changes to a local Git repository (in fact, the Git repository on which the pipeline is based)?

No matter what I try, my script always times out after printing **`Pushing commits to git`**.

**Longer version**

We are migrating existing Java/Maven projects from a Jenkins build server to an Azure DevOps build environment, and I am trying to set up a build pipeline that mimics the Jenkins "Release Staging" functionality.

My first attempt was to call the Maven release plugin directly on the checked out sources. This involved several obstacles, most of which I was able to overcome in one way or the other:

1. The standard Azure DevOps git environment doesn't have the required config values "user.email" and "user.name" set; this can be solved by calling `git config` in a separate "Command Line Script" task prior to pushing.
2. Azure DevOps checks out the sources in a "detached HEAD state" - to solve this problem, the setup script tasks also calls `git checkout master`.

Once this is set up, my Maven call script runs up to the point where the release plugin attempts to push to Git; the corresponding lines in the log file read

```
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git push https://xxx.visualstudio.com/YYY/_git/zzz refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master"
[INFO] Working directory: D:\a\1\s</code>
```

After that, nothing happens (at least, nothing gets logged) until the timeout  strikes:

```
##[error]The operation was canceled.
##[section]Finishing: Maven pom.xml
```

In order to find out what causes this problem I tried a few things, among others,

- disabling the maven call and calling `git push` directly from the script,
- registering a "store" type Git credential helper (assuming that an authentication problem is responsible for the timeout),

but without success. I am now running out of ideas how I could get the `git push` call to work - is there anyone out here who can help me out?

P.S.: As you may be able to tell, I'm rather a newbie as far as Azure DevOps is concerned, so I surely don't know all tricks and features of that system. In particular, I don't know if there is anything that offers the same functionality as the Maven release plugin. We do use the Azure DevOps package management, but we want to keep separate feeds for snapshots and for release builds (the way tools like Nexus do), so we have to have a mechanism for automatically advancing release numbers, checking out and back in and building and publishing the packaged module to the release feed.

If someone can suggest an alternative way to achieve that, I'm open to suggestions as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To push change to Azure DevOps, you should **integrate your credential in Git repo URL**:

- First, create a [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts) if you not have.
- Then use below command to push:

  ```
  git push https://Personal%20Access%20Token:PAT@xxx.visualstudio.com/YYY/_git/zzz master
  ```

Comment: Thanks a whole lot for the answer; using a PAT works (even in Command Line Task).

Comment: Don't PATs expire after 90 days or so? 

My situation is my build process modifies a file in the Git repository on which the pipeline is based and I want to commit/push that modification. 

Isn't there a better option for having Azure DevOps build update its own Git repo (since it's acting in its own context - it's not like it's an external source)? It seems like a hassle to generate the PAT for the service account under which the agent is running every few months.

Comment: An additional challenge to this is if I store my PAT as a "secret variable" in a variable set (so it can be used across builds) it fails to work. So now I have to store it in the variable set as clear text. It works - I just think there has to be a better way.

Comment: Secret variables are not automatically populated to the environment variables of the build agent, so for things like powershell you need to use the explicit **Environment Variables** section of the task to provide the secret to the script. As for the expiration, you can set the expiration up to 12 months.

Comment: You can use a GitHub App, it does not expire.

Answer (score 41):

You shouldn't have to go the PAT route for auth - according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=designer), if your repo is part of the same Azure DevOps project as the build pipeline, credentials should just flow.  Is it possible you haven't authorized the build agent to write to your repos? Two things are needed:

- Under **Project Settings -> Repositories** for your Azure DevOps project, allow the **Project Collection Build Service** entity *Contributor* rights to the appropriate repo (or all project repos).
- Allow scripts to access the OAuth token under the "Agent job" settings:

  [image]

Also note a bad gotcha: this won't work for submodule operations, since DevOps does not automatically flow the credentials to the submodule instances, and the only symptom is a silent hang.  Workaround to flow credentials manually is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50337989/5941604).

Comment: If you're using the newest YAML-based VSTS, "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token", you need to use "persistCredentials: true" in your azure-pipeline.yml file, under "steps: -checkout: self" See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#allow-scripts-to-access-the-system-token

Comment: This the correct answer and should be marked as so by the op.

Comment: can you please share the command line script or detailed process of pushing the local changes from pipeline to repository? I m facing issues and have posted a question, here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57680490/how-to-add-update-files-in-git-repository-from-azure-devops-pipeline-dynamics-36/

Comment: I don't see `Additional options`

Comment: For the newest version: you can directly check how to [grant-version-control-permissions-to-the-build-service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#grant-version-control-permissions-to-the-build-service). After that you can use git commands without any problems.

Answer (score 27):

The answers have become out of date with how Azure Devops works now. To enable authorisation in your pipeline you should use the [checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) schema property in your steps so you can persist the credentials for later git commands.

```
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, you no longer need to use PAT authentication.

You first need to grant access to the Build Service so this account can commit to your repository.

To do so, go to **Your Project > Repositories > Security** and grant the build service **Contribue, Read, Create Tag, Create Branch** permissions.

Then you need to checkout with the below inputs.

*Pipelines created after September 2022 explicitly need fetchDepth set to 0 to fetch all branches, failing to set this will result in minimal branches being fetched which could result in being unable to checkout to your desired branch.*

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  fetchDepth: 0

- bash: |
    echo "This Is Build $(Build.BuildId)" > "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/BuildNumber"
  displayName: Create File

- bash: |
    git config user.name "Example"
    git config user.email "Example@example.com"

    git checkout main --
    git add --all
    git commit -m "Adding Build File"
    git push origin main
  displayName: Git Commit
```

That is all that is required!

source: https://jimferrari.com/2023/03/29/commit-files-to-azure-repos-git-during-azure-pipelines-run/

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem (git push hangs till timeout) in on premise DevOps Server even if Allow scripts to access the OAuth token as well as Repo permissions were correctly set.

In my case the problem was that Build Agent adds a path at the beginning of PATH environment variable - for me it was 'C:\ins\agent\externals\git\cmd\'.
Here an old git version (git version 2.18.0.windows.1) resided and was launched in the context of build agent's pipeline. You can verify this by adding "git --version" call to your build task.

I haven't investigated why the old git version didn't work and simply used the full path qualification for my up-to-date git.exe in the pipeline task

**"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" push origin master**

and with this git version - currently "git version 2.24.0.windows.2" everything works well.
Updating your Build Agent to a version with newer git.exe should solve this problem too, of course.