# Commit a file to remote github repo through Azure DevOps

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, devops

A build definition in Azure DevOps generates a .ipa file(iOS app file). I want to push this .ipa file generated by Azure DevOps build, directly into a remote GitHub Repository.

Comment: It's not recommended to add build out in source control. You have better choice like publishing it to Azure Devops Feed. And if you do want to do this, you can use command-line task or powershell task to run git command to push the file to remote repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A build definition in Azure DevOps generates a .ipa file(iOS app
>   file). I want to push this .ipa file generated by Azure DevOps build,
>   directly into a remote GitHub Repository.

It's **not recommended** to add build output into Source Control. If you have special reason to do this, you can run git commands in [Command-line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) or [Powershell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) to do the commit and push.

My steps to get it work(I use Microsoft windows-hosted agent with one public github repos):

1.Check the log of build task to get the path of Test.txt file

2.Add one Command-Line task after last build task with content similar to this:

```
git clone https://github.com/xxx/TestUpload.git

git config --global user.email xxx@outlook.com

git config --global user.name xxx

copy "D:\a\1\s\xxx\Test.txt" TestUpload

cd TestUpload

git add .

git commit -m "Do sth."

git push https://UserName:UserPassword@github.com/xxx/TestUpload.git master
```

For more details about git push you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55762841/10910450). And since I run the pipeline in windows-hosted agent, so I need to `git clone` the remote repos first.

Also, I'm not sure if you're running that in Mac OS agent, if so, the command-line task is still available for you. But you may need to replace the `copy xxx` and `cd xxx` in script with bash syntax in MacOS.

**Other directions:**

If what you actually need is to download the output xx.ipa file. Consider using Publish [Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops), you can use this task to copy the build output and zip that into one xx.zip file. After the build pipeline succeeds, you can download it from **Summary**:

[image]

If what you want is to have one place to store your file for a long time. Consider using [Azure Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/overview?view=azure-devops), you can use [Universal Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to host the file. It's convenient to publish/download the package to/from feed in local machine or in cloud build pipeline.

Hope all above helps and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to let me know it:)

Comment: Hi Lance, thank you for replying but I was not able to commit the file through the commands you shared with me. So What I did is I clone the GitHub repository on a server. I hosted an agent on this server so that my Azure DevOps task can communicate with this server. Now my Azure DevOps build replaces the IPA file in local GitHub repository in the server, then, I created a command-line task in Azure DevOps to push the IPA file from local GitHub repository to remote GitHub. repository.

Comment: Commands I use in Azure DevOps command line task are : /* cd <repository path>
git status
git add "modified filename"
git commit -m "pushing IPA file from azure pipeline" "modified filename"
git push   */ Now these commands execute successfully except "git push" command because Azure DevOps task continues to run and never stops after showing me commit command message in the logs

Comment: does my above comments make sense?

Comment: Looks like all those succeeds except the git push command, right?  Have you tried shayki Abramczyk's answer here about [git push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55762841/10910450)?

Comment: Thank you. That resolved my issue related to git push command.

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Update**: This can be achieved without needing a PAT token from GitHub.
All that is required is the Service Connection running the pipeline in Azure DevOps has permission to commit to the GitHub repository, you can then run the following below:

```yaml
steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true
  fetchDepth: 0
  
- bash: |
    echo "This Is Build $(Build.BuildId)" > "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/BuildNumber"
  displayName: Create File
  
- bash: |
    git config user.name "John Smith"
    git config user.email "John.Smith@example.com"
  
    git checkout main --
    git add --all
    git commit -m "Adding Build File"
    git push origin main
  displayName: Git Commit
```

Ref: https://jimferrari.com/2023/08/02/commit-files-to-github-during-azure-pipelines-run/