# Duplication of folders when committing to Git Repo from Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dynamics-365, azure-pipelines-release-task

The process outlined below is simplified to demonstrate the issue I'm facing.

**Process:**

[image]

- Create ‘Solutions’ folder in artifact staging directory
  ($.Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory).
- Install required tools
- Export .zip package from Dynamics 365 source system to ‘Solutions’ folder in artifact directory
  ($.Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory\Solutions)
- Publish Artifact ($.Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
- Commit Artifact to a Git Repo

**Behavior on first run of pipeline**

- Correct folder structure is observed.

[image]

**Behavior on second run of pipeline**

- Duplication of root folder

[image]

**Behavior on third run of pipeline**

- Second level down Solution folder is found and updated.
- It is only the second run of the pipeline that duplicates the
  root folder. From here on in, it will find and update the file in the
  duplicated, second level down, folder.

[image]

**Manual Cleanup**

- I can remove the contents of the top-level solutions folder to give
  me this structure – which looks cleaner. Still, this is not ideal given there is an unnecessary Solutions folder with no contents.

[image]

Why is the folder duplicated on the second run of the pipeline, and is there anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the folder duplicated on the second run of the pipeline, and is
>   there anyway to stop this?

The behavior you encountered has something to do with the `Commit to Git task` from Azure Devops Service extension: [Backup data during build or release](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielstocker.backup-data-extension&ssr=false#overview).

I reproduced same issue and found that this strange behavior would happen if your files were placed in one folder (`Solutions`). If our files are in root directory of `Path`, it works well to override the old files with same names.

**To answer your original question:**

1.The reason `why the folder is duplicated on the second run` is related to the design of the task itself instead of Azure Devops Service.

2.And the only way to stop this is to place your `xx.zip` **directly** in path `($.Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` instead of creating `Solutions` folder. Also, you may try opening issue [here](https://github.com/danielstocker/vsts-backup-data-extension/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) to contact the author of this extension. I guess the author would consider modifying the extension if he gets your feedback.

**In addition:**

Though using git-related tasks is very easy to do some git actions, I suggest you can also consider using CMD/PS task to use git commands to do the commit/push/... You can find many topics online and here's one of my [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59854902/10910450).

Hope it helps :)