# How to add/update files in git repository from Azure DevOps Pipeline Dynamics 365 CE

Tags: github, command-line, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dynamics-365

**Short Version**

When a build pipeline is triggered, one of the build pipeline task will get the latest files and it has to be added/updated in the git repository of current running pipeline. I tried to do it by using command line task but its failing as not git repository

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

**Long Version**

I m tried to achieve solution pack and unpack process for dynamics 365 instance. So the build pipeline have the following tasks

1. Export solution from Dynamics 365 and store it in $(build.binariesdirectory)
2. Unpack the solution zip file and store in $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) i.e., adding/updating existing files
3. Command line task to commit and push the files to current pipeline repository

```
ECHO "Setting git config..."
git config --global user.email "xxx@xyz.com"
git config --global user.name "Admin"

ECHO "CHECK GIT STATUS..."
git status

ECHO "GIT ADD..."
git add -A

ECHO "CHECK GIT STATUS..."
git status

ECHO "Commiting the changes..."
git commit -m "Latest Customizations updated"

ECHO "Pushing the changes..."
git push -u origin master

ECHO "Customization Committed Successfully"
```

**Updated**

If a pipeline is created with 2 command line task i.e. one to create a random file in the `Build.Sourcedirectory` and another to commit the changes, then the git commit and push commands are working.

But if we add other tasks (such as unzip files in `Build.Sourcedirectory` directory) before the command line task then getting error as not a repository.

If you see the below screenshot, in the checkout phase the git repo is cloned to `D:\a\1\s`
[image]

And below screenshot is from command line task, where the current working directory is same as the checkout task (i.e., `D:\a\1\s`) and we can see that the ".git" folder is present so the current directory has local repository in it, but still getting error as `fatal: not a git repository`

[image]

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default the source files are checked out to the `Build.SourcesDirectory` (e.g :  Directory: `D:\a\1\s`), it can be considered as a temporary git repository.

According to the error message, it appears that the working directory of the command line task is not under the `Build.SourcesDirectory` and you did't `git checkout` again to that working directory.

So, please try unpack the solution zip file and store in `Build.SourcesDirectory`, then run below Command line to push the commits (it works for me):

```
ECHO "Setting git config..."
git config --global user.email "xxx@xyz.com"
git config --global user.name "Admin"

ECHO "CHECK GIT STATUS..."
git status

git checkout -b master

ECHO "GIT ADD..."
git add -A

ECHO "CHECK GIT STATUS..."
git status

ECHO "Commiting the changes..."
git commit -m "Latest Customizations updated"

ECHO "Pushing the changes..."
git push -u origin master

ECHO "Customization Committed Successfully"
```

Please note that you need to [Grant version control permissions to the build service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#grant-version-control-permissions-to-the-build-service) and enable [Allow scripts to access the system token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#allow-scripts-to-access-the-system-token).

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the information, i have tired they way you have explained and its working if only command line tasks are present, but if i add unzipping task before the command line task then things are not working (please refer updated section in the question for more details)

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a couple of years but for anyone who's having trouble with this is because when you unpack the solution to `$(Build.Sourcedirectory)`, it overwrites the root directory of the repo and causing the `fatal: not a git repository` issue.

To fix the issue, unpack the solution to a sub folder such as `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\$(solutionName)` where `$(solutionName)` is the pipeline variable.