# Automatically copy the databricks notebook from Azure devops main repo to Workspace /live folder using Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-databricks

I am trying to copy the databricks not book from Azure devops Main Repo to Databricks Workspace Live folder. I tried the below Yaml file in my CI pipeline, the pipe line shows success but i dont see the notebook in the Workspace live folder.

```
trigger: none
pool:
vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
  solution: ''
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
steps:
  - task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Deploy Databricks notebooks'
inputs:

  SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/adb-notebook'
  TargetFolder: 'Databricks/Workspace/live'
```

Comment: This looks like a build pipeline to me.  That will build the artefacts for you to then release with a release pipeline.  In order to do that you'll need to connect to the databricks instance using the databricks API and publish your updates through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevOps task is executing on the agent machine, after `CopyFiles@2` completed, the file is only copied to the target folder **on agent machine**, nothing changed on DevOps repo, or databricks workspace.

To copy the files to databricks workspace/live folder, you can install extension  [DevOps for Azure Databricks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=riserrad.azdo-databricks).

My pipeline sample:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- task: configuredatabricks@0
  inputs:
    url: 'https://adb-1399576702.2.azuredatabricks.net'
    token: 'tokevalue'

- task: deploynotebooks@0
  inputs:
    notebooksFolderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/adb-notebook'
    workspaceFolder: '/live'
```

[image]

PS: if you would like to copy the file to **DevOps repo**, you need to [push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52384661/14996050) the file to the repo.

Comment: it works...thanks lot

Comment: Glad to know it works for you! Cheers!