# executing "git pull" in azure DevOps release pipelines results in error -> fatal: could not read Username for

Tags: git, deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

#### Problem

I am trying to deploy my code through a Azure Devops release pipeline by executing a powershell script which checkouts the master branch and pulls on our productive server:

```
cd "C:\..."
git checkout master
git pull
```

this produces an error when I am trying to execute git pull:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://acino.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

The script works without a problem when I execute it from the server itself. It fails only when I use the release pipeline.

#### Troubleshooting

•   The error message would let me believe that the user name is not set when executing git pull, However if I add the following two lines to the code

```
git config user.name 
git config user.email
```

I see the correct user name and email address being printed.

•   The other guess is that it is trying to pull from the wrong origin, since 'https://acino.visualstudio.com' is not the URL of my repository. So I have tried also to append the repository name to git pull

```
git pull https://URL to my repository
with no luck.
```

I am therefore don't really understand what the problem is really. Any input, comment,suggestion is welcome.

FYI: I am aware that executing git pull in a release pipeline is not perhaps the standard way of deploying code. I have also build other more conventional deployment pipelines which work. However, due to our directory/project structure using git pull would be optimal solution as I see it.

Kind Regards,
Rok Bohinc

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use git pull command with this format:

```
git pull {URL} {remote branch}:{local branch}
```

And inserting [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) into the URL would provide credentials to resolve login issues. You can create a new PAT manually or use the [System.AccessToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#systemaccesstoken) (more recommended), the final format on my side would be:

```
git pull https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{RepoName} master:master

git pull https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_git/{RepoName} master:master
```

It looks your project is still the old format `xxx.visualstudio.com/...`, so your final formats would be something like:

```
git pull https://PAT:{PAT}@xxx.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_git/{RepoName} master:master

git pull https://$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN@xxx.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_git/{RepoName} master:master
```

With PAT or `System.AccessToken` in URL, you don't need to config the username and password. Just remember we should enable [Allow scripts to access the OAuth token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56734304/10910450) so that we can access `System.AccessToken`.

Comment: @RokBohinc You're welcome. If my answer is useful, you could [mark it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) via clicking the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons of my answer. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Please try use `System.AccessToken` in git config as it written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45820526/vsts-build-git-submodule-automatization/50337989#50337989)

```
$mods = (git submodule status) | % { ($_.Trim() -split " ")[1] }
$baserepo = ($env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_URI).TrimEnd($env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME)
foreach($mod in $mods)
{
cd $mod
$cmd = 'git config http.' + $baserepo + $mod + '.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer ' + $env:System_AccessToken + '"'
write $cmd
iex $cmd
cd ..
}
```

[image]

You can also consider [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365812/push-to-local-azure-devops-git-from-build-pipeline) useful.